# Как вывести данные с Excel в консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите как можно вывести в консоль данные из эксель после записи в него из базы

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('./name.db')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from name', conn)
df.to_excel(r'./info.xlsx', index=False)

dff = pandas.read_excel(open('./info.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')
```

пытаюсь прочитать файл, выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл эксель вот так выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новая ошибка после исправления предыдущей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('./info.xlsx')
# --> ^^ <--- используйте алиас "pd" вместо "pandas"
```

`pd.read_excel()` принимает имя файла в качестве первого аргумента. Если не указать имя Excel листа (параметр `sheet_name`), то `pd.read_excel()` по умолчанию будет читать первый лист.

---

чтобы вывести содержимое DataFrame в консоль:

```
print(df2)
```